# how to prevent django database from using deleted objects' id for new objects?

Tags: python, database, django, sqlite, django-database

I'm writing a `django` website with a `sqlite` database, I have a model in my website like this :

```
class Foo(models.model):
   name = models.Charfield(max_length=30)
```

the database creates an `Id` column for this class that is unique, consider that I create an object from class `Foo` and delete it and create another object `g`, their `Id` is the same :

```
>> f = Foo.objects.create(name="fooname")
>> f.id
4
>> f.delete()
>> g = Foo.objects.create(name="fooname2")
>> g.id
4
```

but I don't want the database to use an old deleted object's `id` for a newly created one, How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that was [fixed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/eade315da1c8372ac1dfcf1fd20ea87f454d71ac) in Django 1.7, see:

- [sqlite3 backend: AutoField values aren't monotonically increasing](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10164).

Quote from [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/):

> AutoField columns in SQLite databases will now be created using the
>   AUTOINCREMENT option, which guarantees monotonic increments. This will
>   cause primary key numbering behavior to change on SQLite, becoming
>   consistent with most other SQL databases. This will only apply to
>   newly created tables. If you have a database created with an older
>   version of Django, you will need to migrate it to take advantage of
>   this feature.

Comment: So the bug was only for Sqlite? will using MySql also solve my problem?(without updating django)

Comment: @Navid777 the bug was in django, switching to mysql would help, yes.